# How can I join the same table to bring me one result?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to create a query than bring me the following result:

```
Product | attibutname | attibutname      | Value |
   5547 | Lacoste     | Enable / Disable | 20
   5548 | Vans        | Enable / Disable | 10
```

The table are look like this:

```
id | Product | Attributname     | value
 1 |    5547 | Brand            | Lacoste
 2 |    5547 | Woman /Mens      | 1
 3 |    5547 | Enable / Disable | 20
 4 |    5548 |  Brand           | Vans
 2 |    5548 | Woman /Mens      | 0
 3 |    5548 | Enable / Disable | 10
```

`

Comment: this is a PIVOT or UNPIVOT operation - but you do not have enough in your table to make the proper decision about which values go in to which columns..

Comment: First you need to decide which DBMS you are using. The answer may be very different from those two products.

Comment: I'm guessing that that's not really the result your looking for.

Comment: Assuming you are using | to indicate column separations your sample data is a bit a challenge since the 4th row has more columns than the other rows. This might be a good place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have a real table than look like the example it com from Microsft Dynamic AX. so the thing than I want to do is base on the product and bring me brand and enable value.

Comment: Please tag properly.  It's either MySQL or SQL Server, can't be both.  You get different answer for different dbms.  It's useless if we post answer to the wrong dbms.

Answer (score -1):

Something like the following is how you would join the table to itself(with assumptions from what you have provided). You would need to alias each copy so you know if you are talking about the brand or a different attribute row of the table.

```
Select b.Product, b.value [Attributename1], g.Attributename, g.value 
  from myItemTable b 
  join myItemTable g ON g.id = b.id 
 Where b.Attributename = 'Brand'
   and g.Attributename = 'Enable / Disable'
```

Comment: I have no problem with my answer being voted down, just please let me know why. As far as I know, you are just out there voting down stuff to get a badge.